# CSS pseudo selector :target and trigger source

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Having `html` code with several hash links (e.g.`href="#login"`) and css using pseudo selector `:target` for animation, such as

```
#login:target ~ #wrapper #console {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-name: scaleOut;
    -moz-animation-name: scaleOut;
    -o-animation-name: scaleOut;
    -ms-animation-name: scaleOut;
    animation-name: scaleOut;
}
```

I would like to add a feature of conditional behavior, based on **"source"** of the trigger event.

Let's say the `html` code with

```
<a class="hidden" id="login"></a>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="console" class="animate">
...
```

has somewhere also two links

```
<a id="link_1" href="#login">
```

and

```
<a id="link_2" href="#login">
```

both pointing to `#login`. Is it possible to modify `css` to have different behavior for each of links? In my case, is it possible by pure `html` and `css` to do different kinds of animation for both links?

Comment: Like a[href="#login"] { ... } ?

Comment: @kunalbhat - both links have `href="#login"`

Comment: Ah yes, OK I see that now. Having a little trouble understanding the question.

Comment: So, you're trying to change the animation on the #login element based on if #link_1 or #link_2 were clicked?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird - Yes, correct. In the code example above, element with `id` #console is getting animated, but I would like to do different css code (animation) based on source of trigger event, so if user click on link with `id` #link_1, it will do animation #1 and if user click on link with `id` #link_2, it will do animation #2.

Answer (score 0):

No. `:target` is the only CSS selector of its type; for any other “behaviour”, you need JavaScript or something server-side.

The closest you can get is `#login1` and `#login2`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, as you ask it, since CSS has no capacity to conditionally-assess the source of the activity, and is only able to 'react' to the end-result, without the ability to reference the source of the action that 'caused' the `:target` selector to match.

That said, if you're able to change your HTML, and one of the links, you could approximate it:

```
    <a id="link_1" href="#hidden">Link One</a>

    <a id="link_2" href="#login">Link Two</a>

    <div id="hidden"></div>
    <a class="hidden" id="login"></a>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="console" class="animate">
    </div>

You can target differently:

#hidden:target + #login {
    /* style, or trigger animation */
}

#login:target {
    /* style, or trigger different animation */
}
```

The problem, of course, is that this clearly doesn't directly cause the `:target` selector to match the relevant element in both cases, so the answer must remain, basically: 'no,' this is a case in which JavaScript is probably the only real solution to meet your needs.